# Bitcoin Core telling me transaction is not "trusted"

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, unconfirmed-transactions, bitcoin-cli

I'm running a full node without the GUI, so I'm controlling it with `bitcoin-cli`.

I sent bitcoin to another address, same as I always do, but this time I can't pull up the transaction on any of the block explorers and when I use `bitcoin-cli gettransaction ad2dfbd06b15f0721c2c1864e4cf0989833727c6eec038472c2a2789f4b5d024`, it comes back with:

```
  "amount": -0.01949732,
  "fee": -0.00007460,
  "confirmations": 0,
  "trusted": false,
  "txid": "ad2dfbd06b15f0721c2c1864e4cf0989833727c6eec038472c2a2789f4b5d024",
  "walletconflicts": [
  ],
  "time": 1479664206,
  "timereceived": 1479664206,
  "bip125-replaceable": "unknown"
```

I've never seen `"trusted": false` on any other transaction, so I assume that has something to do with it, but I can't find any information online to tell me what it means.

**EDIT:**
Pasting the hex format of the raw transaction into blockchain.info/pushtx and pushing it that way has set it to `trusted: true` and now it's showing up. I'd still like to know why it happened and/or how I can fix it myself without relying on blockchain.info's pushtx tool.

Comment: This field is discussed in [the 0.12.0 changelog](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/57b34599b2deb179ff1bd97ffeab91ec9f904d85/doc/release-notes/release-notes-0.12.0.md), see under "Negative confirmations".  I'm not sure what "coming from ourself" means, though.  The code that implements it is in `CWalletTx::IsTrusted()` in `wallet.cpp`.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks! I'm still mostly clueless but at least now I have a new lead to look at

Comment: @NateEldredge: "Coming from ourself" means that your wallet controls the private keys corresponding to the transaction inputs.

Answer (score 3):

A transaction will be distrusted if

- it conflicts with a transaction already in the blockchain, or
- it is from someone else, and it is not confirmed.

A transaction will be trusted if

- it has confirmations.

If a transaction is not trusted, the client won't create transactions that spend it. (You wouldn't want a transaction you created to be in limbo because one of its inputs wasn't confirmed.)

Once that transaction is confirmed, the trusted field in `listtransactions` will be true.

Comment: But this IS a transaction I created and it's currently in limbo.

Comment: https://blockchain.info/search/ad2dfbd06b15f0721c2c1864e4cf0989833727c6eec038472c2a2789f4b5d024

Comment: It can also show as nontrusted if the transaction isn't in your node's memory pool.

Comment: But if I sent it, why would it not be in my memory pool? Or how would I check if its in the mempool? And how would I add it?

Comment: Hmm. Could you try `getrawtransaction <txhash>` followed by `sendrawtransaction <tx>` ?

Comment: `$ bitcoin-cli getrawtransaction ad2dfbd06b15f0721c2c1864e4cf0989833727c6eec038472c2a2789f4b5d024
error code: -5
error message:
No information available about transaction`